# How to set the connection Timeout for SOAP?

Tags: java, soap, httpclient

I am using the following sample code `soap`

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory =
        new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
        .addInterceptorFirst(new RemoHttpHeadersInterceptor())
        .setMaxConnTotal(config.getDefaultMaxTotalConnections())
        .setMaxConnPerRoute(config.getDefaultMaxRouteConnections())
        .build();
    return httpClient;
```

How can I set the connection timeout value? I am not able to find the `setTimeout` api anywhere.

Comment: Hi, please be more precise: [httpclient] DO NOT USE:  [apache-commons-httpclient], [apache-httpclient-4.x], [jetty-httpclient], [java-http-client]?

Comment: for [apache-httpclient-4.x], see: [`RequestConfig`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.5/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html) / [example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=apache%2Fcloudstack%2Fcloudstack-master%2Fagent%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fcloud%2Fagent%2Fdirect%2Fdownload%2FHttpsDirectTemplateDownloader.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to configure it is to use a RequestConfig:

Example:

```
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;


 RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
         .setConnectTimeout(5000)
         .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
         .setSocketTimeout(5000).build();

 HttpClients.custom()
         .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
         .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
         .addInterceptorFirst(new RemoHttpHeadersInterceptor())
         .setMaxConnTotal(config.getDefaultMaxTotalConnections())
         .setMaxConnPerRoute(config.getDefaultMaxRouteConnections())
         .build();
```